# How can I add additional columns to the Rally.ui.tree.PortfolioTree

Tags: rally

I'm trying to modify the standard Portfolio Hierarchy report to include additional columns.  But I can't see a way to do this reading the portfoliotree docs.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, adding additional columns isn't directly supported right now.

You could override the treeitem template (as shown in the Customizing the UI section of https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.tree.Tree) to add the additional fields you want to display. This may not be enough for what you want to do, but you can give it a go.

The next SDK release will come with the hierarchical Tree Grid, which will be a more polished version of the Rally.ui.tree and should be just as configurable as a regular grid. Until then, I hope this helps!